# How does pipeline affect Select-Object?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a table in PowerShell with custom headers, I am able to do this with

```
"var" | Select @{n="First";e={"1"}}, @{n="Second";e={"2"}},@{n="Third";e={"3"}}

First Second Third
----- ------ -----
1     2      3
```

However, without the initial object, there is no output

```
Select @{n="First";e={"1"}}, @{n="Second";e={"2"}},@{n="Third";e={"3"}}
```

I can't tell the difference between these other than one is after a pipeline while the other isn't. Why won't this work?

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cmdlet `Select-Object` (alias `Select`) has one required parameter which is `-inputObject` Which also happens to be the object that gets passed through the pipeline.

```
Select-Object -InputObject "Example" -Property @{n="First";e={"1"}}, @{n="Second";e={"2"}},@{n="Third";e={"3"}}
```

Will have the output

```
First Second Third
----- ------ -----
1     2      3
```

While without `-InputObject`, it will not have an output **because there is no input** (Thanks @mklement0).

```
Select-Object "Example" -Property @{n="First";e={"1"}}, @{n="Second";e={"2"}},@{n="Third";e={"3"}}
# No Output
```

and with the pipeline, it will

```
"Example" | Select-Object "Example" -Property @{n="First";e={"1"}}, @{n="Second";e={"2"}},@{n="Third";e={"3"}}

First Second Third
----- ------ -----
1     2      3
```

The `-inputObject` Parameter will usually contain the table you would like to select columns from or other things (if you are not using expressions).

Comment: What does the `InputObject` parameter do?

Comment: If you are selecting a certain column instead of doing an expression, the table goes in the `inputObject` parameter

Comment: Nice, but worth adding to "without -InputObject, it will not have an output": because there is _no input_.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer from @Neko answers the exact question, I think it is important to mention that the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) cmdlet is *not mentioned to construct new custom objects*:

Quote from the [`Get-Help Select-Object -Online`](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2096716):

> The `Select-Object` cmdlet selects specified properties of an object
> or set of objects.

In other words; the object needs to exist in order to select its properties.

For what you are doing with

```
"var" | Select @{n="First";e={"1"}}, @{n="Second";e={"2"}},@{n="Third";e={"3"}}`
```

you're creating a new `pscustomobject` by removing all the default properties from the `"Var"` (string) object and adding new properties with a hard-coded (static) expression which is a long-winded syntax and quiet expensive for building a new object.

To construct a new [`pscustomobject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7) ("table"), you can simply use the constructor syntax:

```
[pscustomobject]@{First = '1'; Second = '2'; Third = '3'}
```

For legacy (prior PSv3) POwerShell versions:

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{First = '1'; Second = '2'; Third = '3'}
```